# ASP.Net HTTPHandler to match path with specified number of segments

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

Currently in my solution I have an HttpHandler that responds to an request that contains "data" in the url.

```
 <handlers>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
  <add name="MyHandler" verb="GET,POST" path="data/**" type="org.myorg.MyHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>      
</handlers>
```

How can I match on URLs containing "data" but have a defined number of segments after the matching segment; say 5?

> data/firstSeg/secondSeg/thirdSeg/forthSeg/fifthSeg

Is this possible to configure in the web.config?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to my question. I was using:

```
> path = data/**/**/**/**/**
```

Double '**' means 'Everything to the right'. When what I need is:

```
> path = data/*/*/*/*/*/
```

Comment: Useful thing to know + 1  Don't forget in a couple of days time SO will let you mark your own answer as accepted so please remember to come back and do that